# Returning html from a function

Tags: php, html

So being a newb, this is just a best practices question but is it better to return html from a function like this:

```
function returnHtml($userName)
{   
$htmlMsg = "
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Return the html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You've received an email from: ".$userName.".</p>
    </body>
</html>
";

return $htmlMsg;
}
```

Or like this:

```
function returnHtml($userName)
{
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Return the html</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You've received an email from: <?php $userName ?>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
```

The second one is much easier than the first since you don't have to turn the html into a string, but I'm wondering if the lack of a return statement would cause any unforeseen problems.  Thank you for any advice!

Comment: The two do different things. The first one returns HTML, but the second one prints the HTML.

Comment: Those are not really the same thing. The second one doesn't return html. It echoes it out.

Comment: Aside from the return/not return issue, you should escape any variable data with `htmlspecialchars()` if it is to be used in HTML.  Also, your second example doesn't actually output `$userName`.  You need `echo` for that.

Comment: Best practise would probably be to use neither method :) I can't think of a case where putting a chunk of html within a php function would be better than an alternative approach. From what you have there, just seems you require a email html template which requires one php variable parsed into it?

Comment: @SteveH he must have his reasons. we are her to help him with is issues... this might just be an example of what he wants done

Comment: @Steve H, what would be an alternative approach other than the template you mention?  I was asking the question because I have an error message echoed to the screen via my first example and an email to be sent out using the second example but I wanted to know if I could use just the first one to keep things standardized.

Comment: @Noah, fair enough but he did specify 'best practices question', his reasons (in his own admission) is that he is a noob, so I was just pointing out that perhaps now would be a good time to rethink this function entirely?

Comment: @SteveH ahh i understand what your saying

Comment: @Freethinker  - In that case out of the two functions the first is better, the second one is just a dirty hack. I still think (depending on how many html elements you want) perhaps look at creating separate files for your html and either parsing these directly in the function or use the output buffer (ob_start(),  ob_get_contents(), et al) for parsing the PHP variables. It is 99.99% better to use a return statement in a function rather than echo / print (perhaps unless for Ajax purposes). Do you mean you have an error because of the 1st function or you want something printed to the screen?

Comment: No, I don't have an error because of it.  I'm using that style of function to return a bit of html to a spot in my form to display an error message if the validation fails.

Comment: @Freethinker if you wanted to mix the html and php like that it would be better to put all your php logic above your html. Then just set a bool variable for the validation success, and use a if statement within your html to display the actual message. Anyway I assume you have got what you wanted to work now, but in future try to separate the html and php as much as possible, this will help with code reuse, but more importantly help separate your concerns (i.e. readability of your code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two functions you've posted do different things. The first returns a string of html, the second prints the string.

Essentially it depends on what you want to accomplish with the function. If you want to print some HTML, the second function is better, if you want to have some HTML in a string, the first is better.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using this to get HTML code using a AJAX, GET, or POST method then i would go with the first one because anything that is echoed from the php file is put into a variable that you can use.

For instance:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "document.php",
    data: {data: "some information to send"},
    success: function(echoed_data) {
        $('#element').html(echoed_data);
    }
});
```

document.php

```
function returnHtml($userName) {   
    $htmlMsg = "
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Return the html</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>You've received an email from: ".$userName.".</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    ";

    echo $htmlMsg;
}
```

this would use AJAX to send and receive data from "document.php" and then enters the HTML code that is echoed from the .php file into a certain element.

Comment: `returnHtml()` needs to be called. Or removed. And set `$userName` to `$_POST['data']`

Comment: @JDavis its just an example. idk what he is doing with the rest of his code so im just showing him what echoing out the HTML code does when using AJAX

Comment: Sure, it's probably helpful, I just thought that if he or anyone else tried to copy and paste that into `document.php` they might not understand why it wouldn't work. Thats all.